# How to restore Status bar in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox

In FF4b7, I think, the status bar went away, and so now when you hover over a link, it tries to squeeze this into the right half of the URL bar.  I'm always looking at something like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.o...>>http://en.wikipedia.org...ation
```

This is almost completely useless to me.  I have *no idea* where this link is going to go.

Is there any way, through `about:config` or an extension, to bring the old, usable status bar back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you should have a look here:
http://maketecheasier.com/restore-status-bar-in-firefox-4/2010/11/25

Two approaches (involving extensions) are listed there.

Being a Firefox 4 Beta 7 user myself, your question inspired me to try the first option listed there, [Link Target Display](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/55724/), which takes the same approach as Google Chrome does. I'm quite happy with it.

**Edit:** After trying both extensions for a while, I decided I actually like [Status-4-Evar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/235283/) better.

Comment: That's better than nothing, but it suffers from Chrome's problems (crops the middle of URLs, even though it has the entire width of the window), and adds a couple new ones of its own (doesn't move out of the way for URLs on the bottom row).

Comment: Did you try the other extension listed there, Status-4-Evar?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/235283/